# How can I bind an ItemsControl.ItemsSource with a property in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-controls

I have a simple window :

```
<Window x:Class="WinActivityManager"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="lvItems" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the associated code behind :

```
public partial class WinActivityManager : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }

    public WinActivityManager()
    {
        Activities = new ObservableCollection<Activity>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Other code ...
}
```

If I write the following binding in the window constructor :

```
lvItems.ItemsSource = Activities;
```

then my ListView is automatically updated when I add or remove elements from `Activities`.

**How should I write the binding in XAML?**
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvItems" ItemsSource="{Binding=Activities}" />
```

How do I make this work in XAML?

Comment: Have you tried `ItemsSource={Binding Activities}`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What @JesseJames says is true but not enough.

You have to put

```
private ObservableCollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
```

as

```
public ObservableCollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
```

And the binding should be:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Activities}" />
```

Regards,

Comment: This work but to set DataContext I think it's better way is like @Farhad Jabiyev write.

Answer (score 15):

You must set DataContext to **this** like others answered, but you can set `DataContext` through `xaml` also:

```
<Window x:Class="WinActivityManager"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="lvItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Activities}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Really `{Binding=Activities}`? Dont you mean `{Binding Activities}` or `{Binding Path=Activities}`? Never saw this one before...

Comment: @Jan'splite'K. It was typo ) Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Set `DataContext = this` in the Window constructor.

```
public WinActivityManager()
{
    Activities = new ObservableCollection<Activity>();
    DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Then you will be able to bind Activities as you want: `<ListView x:Name="lvItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}" />`

Comment: `{Binding=Activities}` looks like a typo: `=` shouldn't be there

Answer (score 2):

That's because the data context of your view hasn't been set. You could either do this in the code behind:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Alternatively, you could set the Window's `DataContext` to itself - `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

You're much better off though investigating the [MVVM design pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx), and [using an MVVM framework](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx).