# C# WPF: Place UserControl in DataGridRow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, user-controls

I'm creating a WPF Application in C#. In my window there is a DataGrid. In the Grid are 2 columns. The first Column contains only strings. In the second column I want to display a usercontrol I created.

The UserControl (called: ProductControl) consists of 3 buttons and 3 textboxes.

This is the XAML code for the control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CARDS.ProductControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="95" Width="273">
  <Grid Margin="-23,0,0,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="24*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="29*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="32*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="btnSP_P" Content="SP/P" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnNM_M" Content="NM/M" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnHP" Content="HP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="215,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtNM_M" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="27,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtSP_P" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="27,4,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtHP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="27,3,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" Grid.Row="3"/>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is the C# code for the control:

```
public partial class ProductControl : UserControl
    {
        public String NM_M { get; protected set; }
        public String SP_P { get; protected set; }
        public String HP { get; protected set; }

        public ProductControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Set(String nm_m, String sp_p, String hp)
        {
            this.NM_M = nm_m;
            this.SP_P = sp_p;
            this.HP = hp;

            txtHP.Text = hp;
            txtNM_M.Text = nm_m;
            txtSP_P.Text = sp_p;
        }
    }
```

I have 2 classes that contains the data that need to be displayed in the datagrid:

```
class DataItems {
    public List<DataItemCard> items = new List<DataItemCard>();
}
class DataItemCard {
    public String Reference { get; set; }
    public ProductControl Products { get; set; }
}
```

The instance of DataItems is used as the ItemsSource for the DataGrid.
The String is displayed correctly, but in the second column just stands the type: 'CARDS.ProductControl'.

The DataGrid is declared in the XAML file as:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridDisplayCards" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="3.046,4.843" Height="273" Width="284">
```

My question: How can I display my control in the cell?

Thank you all for the help and external links. It works now, the problem was actually the assembly.
I used:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:OUTPOST_BUY_IN_SINGLE_CARDS;assembly=OUTPOST_BUY_IN_SINGLE_CARDS"
```

But it just needed to be:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:OUTPOST_BUY_IN_SINGLE_CARDS"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` when you want to display a custom control within a `DataGrid` ...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You will need to add an `xmlns` directive like `xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyControls;assembly=MyControls"` to your Window, and then reference the control like this:

```
       <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MyControls:ProductControl /><!--You will need to add your binding expressions to the ProductControl element-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This existing question should help you iron out any binding problems you have ...

[How to bind a user control using as a DataGridTemplateColumn failed in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907169/how-to-bind-a-user-control-using-as-a-datagridtemplatecolumn-failed-in-wpf)

Comment: The namespace is now included and I read the link, as Denis Thomas said, I can't drag the control in my window and the Control is not found in my namespace. The namespace is empty.

Comment: I can't explain adding a namespace better than this ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb514546%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use a TemplateColum. For that column type you could define the content in XAML. Therefore you could place your control inside the column template:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TemplateColumn">
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <YourControl></YourControl>
            </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: I have tried it, but for some reason, the name of my control is not found.

Comment: Is the control working outside of the DataGrid? (Probably the namspace is not specified correctly...)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge there are two way to do it.

1. Solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093429/add-a-user-control-to-a-wpf-window)

   Add a reference to your xaml. If xaml cannot find your control its normally because you forget to add assembly. Assembly is very important if you are refering a control from other project.

   ```
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyControls;assembly=MyControls"
   ```

   Then you can use the control like

   ```
   <controls:ControlClass....>
   ```

   Sometimes, you need to rebuilt the solution to make the intellisense work (btw intellisense is stupid so don't expect too much from intellisense /_/)
2. Using [Content Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) to add user control.
   This solution is normally used if you want to add the user control dynamically in code behind.

   First you add this line in .xaml

   ```
   <DataTemplate>
      <ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl1"></ContentControl>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

   Then in code behind, add

   ```
    ContentControl1.Content = new YourControlHere();
   ```

Comment: The solution has been rebuilt a lot of times, and it still can't find it. The line is included also.